# Convert Javascript Object to different alternatives array keeping keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, post

I'm trying to convert this Javascript object:

```
image_uploads: [
  0: {
    upload_id: 50,
  },
  1: {
    upload_id: 51,
  },
  2: {
    upload_id: 52,
  },
]
```

Into different entries using this format to be able to send it in the body of a POST request:

```
image_uploads[0][upload_id] = 50
image_uploads[1][upload_id] = 51
image_uploads[2][upload_id] = 52
```

Probably needing an array of those entries like:

```
params: [
  "image_uploads[0][upload_id]": 50,
  "image_uploads[1][upload_id]": 51,
  "image_uploads[2][upload_id]": 52,
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your javascript object is not an object but a weird hybrid between object and array..

Comment: Are you using jQuery? `jQuery.param(object)` will create that format.

Comment: @Barmar No, I'm using Angular6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep appending keys inside an array. You can do that with:

```
var image_uploads = [];
image_uploads.push({'upload_id': 50});
image_uploads.push({'upload_id': 51});
image_uploads.push({'upload_id': 52});
```

Then you can access them like so:

```
image_uploads[0]['upload_id']; // 50
image_uploads[1]['upload_id']; // 51
image_uploads[2]['upload_id']; // 52
```

For both creating your array and accessing them, you can also use loops.

Comment: He's trying to create the serialized parameter names to send to a server.